# Differencce between the given codes for combination sum problem

Tags: java, recursive-backtracking

Ok, I have been trying to find the mistake in my code or the place where it changes from the given code.
There are two codes here
code #1-

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> combinationSum(int[] candidates, int target) {
      List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
      Arrays.sort(candidates);
      backtrack(list, new ArrayList<>(), candidates, target, 0);
      return list;  
    }
    public void backtrack(List<List<Integer>> list, List<Integer> temp, int[] nums, int remain, int start) {
        if(remain < 0) return;
        else if (remain == 0) list.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
        else {
            for(int i = start; i < nums.length; i ++) {
                temp.add(nums[i]);
                backtrack(list, temp, nums, remain - nums[i], i);
                temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

code #2-

```
class Solution {
    public static void combi(int n, int[] arr, int tar, List<List<Integer>> res, List<Integer> opt, int sum){
        if(sum>tar){
            return;
        }else if(sum == tar){
            res.add(new ArrayList<>(opt));
          
        }else{
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
             opt.add(arr[i]);
             combi(n, arr, tar, res, opt, sum+arr[i]);
             opt.remove(opt.size()-1);
             
        }}
    }
    public List<List<Integer>> combinationSum(int[] arr, int tar) {
       List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
       Arrays.sort(arr);
       combi(arr.length, arr, tar, res, new ArrayList<>(), 0);
       return res; 
    }
```

code 2 is written by me now i want to know why the code1 is giving only the unique sol'n when i believe it should give all the possible sol'n, duplicates too as my code gives. I dont get it can you please tell me what is the difference.

so the test case is

[2,3,6,7]

and my code gives
`your text`
[[2,2,3],[2,3,2],[3,2,2],[7]]

```
type here
```

but the code gives

[[2,2,3],[7]]

One thing I can do is use set to get the unique sol'n but what ever the first code does is much easier I just don't get why the code give unique sol'ns only.

Comment: Do not tag this as `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Answer (score 0):

The key difference between the two codes is the `start` parameter in `backtrack()` method of code #1, which ensures you only move forward or stay at the current element when making recursive calls. This avoids permutations of the same combination without needing a Set for deduplication.

- In code #1: `backtrack(list, temp, nums, remain - nums[i], i);`
  Notice the `i` in the recursive call. This ensures you reuse the current number or use numbers that come after it, avoiding duplicates.
- In code #2: `combi(n, arr, tar, res, opt, sum+arr[i]);`
  There's no such constraint. You always start from `i=0`, leading to permutations of the same combination.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful